# Android bluetooth in a service stops sending data after 561K

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth

I wrote a service to send sensor data over bluetooth on android. Although I got no errors my C# client stops getting data after I sent exactly 561K data. At this moment it seems like my android continues to send data but my client doesn't get any. After a while, android also stops sending data. I tried different configurations. My program always stops sending data after "Service->Server". I don't get any errors but it stops sending. Here is android program.

```
@Override
public synchronized int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"onStartCommand");
    if(isRunning)
        Log.e(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "I am already running");
    else
    {
        isRunning = true;

        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        if(selectedDevice == null)
        {Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"null it is "); return -1;}
        connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
        connect.start();
        mHandler =new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                switch(msg.what){
                case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                    connected = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", 0).show();
                    //connected.write(("Connected").getBytes());
                    Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "we are connected");
                    isConnected  = true;
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((byte[]) msg.obj).toString(), 0).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        mSensor = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sSensor = mSensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
        mSensor.registerListener(this, sSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

//      sSensor = mSensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
//      mSensor.registerListener(this, sSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        sSensor = mSensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        mSensor.registerListener(this, sSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Sensor data arrived");
    if(isConnected  )
    {
        String toSend = Integer.toString(event.sensor.getType())+ ":" + Long.toString(event.timestamp)+ ":";
        for(float f : event.values){
            toSend = toSend + Float.toString(f)+":";
        }
//          
        connected.write(toSend.getBytes());
    }


}


private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"connectThread started successfully");
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection


        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
            Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"connectThread connect successfully");
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"connectThread connect exception");
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }

        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    public boolean shouldContinue = true;
    int nBytes =0;
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;


        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"connectedThread sockets");
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while(shouldContinue) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer = new byte[1024];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                Log.e(EXTRA_MESSAGE, " We read");
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"Service->Server");
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            nBytes += bytes.length;
            Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"ok" + String.valueOf(nBytes ));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"exception");
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            shouldContinue = false;
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Also my c# thread is as follows

```
 public void ServerConnectThread()
    {
        serverStarted = true;
        int counter =  0;
        updateUI("Server started, waiting for clients");
        BluetoothListener blueListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
        blueListener.Start();
        BluetoothClient conn = blueListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
        updateUI("Client has connected");

        Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //handle server connection
                byte[] received = new byte[1024];
                mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
                counter += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received).Length;
                String[] fields  = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received).Split(':');
                double[] data = new double[3];
                for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++) data[i-2] = double.Parse(fields[i]);

                 //mSource.notifyObserver(Int16.Parse(fields[0]), data);

                updateUI(counter.ToString() + " "+ fields[2]+ ":" + fields[3] + ":" + fields[4]);
                byte[] sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");
                mStream.Write(sent, 0, sent.Length);
            }
            catch (IOException exception)`enter code here`
            {
                updateUI("Client has disconnected!!!!");
            }
        }

    }
```

One final thing is I've found thousands of 561K android program which sounded a little interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my own problem. Basically I m sending a reply from my client when I got the sensor data and It is not handled by android app.